# How to monitor SQL Server Jobs in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, monitor

I need an application to monitor SQL Server Jobs.For example:I have CPU usage graphic,In time scale between 14:00:200 and 14:20:000 156. numbered job should be seen.I want to make something like this.I'm a rookie programmer.Is it something possible?Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

Source : http://sqlstudies.com/2013/09/05/a-t-sql-query-to-get-current-job-activity/

Comment: You might want to add **WHERE ja.start_execution_date BETWEEN '2012-04-10 14:00:00' AND '2014-09-10 14:20:00'**.

Comment: is it possible to show this values in graphic?and how?I can get the values and show it on a datagridview but I'm not very good with chart.Chart is also going to be in my application

Comment: Really out of scope for 1 question, but take a look at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/charting-in-wpf/